# XAMPP Tomcat/Error starting Tomcat

Tags: java

Can someone help me solve this:

> "Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1 Make sure you have Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free.  Check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information."

I have installed Java JDK. Thanks

Comment: Do you have JDK or JRE installed?

Comment: and did you `Check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information."`?  If so, please add the info you find there.

Comment: Required ports are free?

Comment: @fvu the logs folder says "NOTEMPTY"

Comment: @Math, yes i'm assuming....not sure how to check that.

Comment: please, type `java -version` in your `cmd` and tell us what you get

Comment: do you use XAMPP, this error occurs when you try to start Tomcat?

Comment: @Math, I get java version "1.7.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server UM (build 24.45-b08 mixed mode) and yes I do use XAMPP

Answer (score 15):

Go to **https://youtu.be/JmmaeS7UZRk** youtube link for better understanding:

1. we need to create an Environment Variable "JAVA_HOME".
   and give the vale as JDK installation directory path.
   Ex: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66"
2. we need to create an Environment Variable "JRE_HOME". and give the vale as JRE installation directory path. Ex: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66"
3. Go to your "tomcat" installation directory and then "conf" folder. Ex:   "C:\xampp\tomcat\conf".
4. Edit these given files with these values:
   i) open **server.xml** file which is located inside **conf** folder. Go to line number "70" and change the "port" number "8080" as something else for example "9999" and save it.
   ii) open **context.xml** file which is located inside "conf" folder and go to line number "19" and change `<Context>` tag as `<Context reloadable="true">` and save it.
5. close the "XAMPP" App and restart it.
6. Now go to the "Config" Option inside "XAMPP" application i.e top right corner of the XAMPP app. then go to the  "Service and Port Settings" then go to the "Tomcat" tab and put "9999" as the "HTTP Port" value and save it. Not restart XAMPP.
7. Now try to start "Tomcat" Server.
8. Open your browser and type localhost:9999 in the browser url and hit enter.

Comment: Apache and MySql stopped working after this!

Answer (score 4):

Run XAMPP with "Administrator Privileges" to start Tomcat.
It is as simple as that.

Comment: This did not fix it for me.

Answer (score 3):

`WINDOWS-KEY + PAUSE` (shortcut to System Properties), in system properties choose
Advanced system settings --> Environment variables --> add a new System variable:

Fill in:

Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`
Variable value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0` (or whatever your location/version is)

klik ok and done(maybe you should restart tomcat after this)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your port. Maybe you have another app running in the port 8080.

If you run in the 8081 for example it will run correctly

Answer (score 1):

Is your java registered in the enviorement variables.

If you open console Win+R -> CMD and write java --version (For JDK) and java -version (for JRE) do you get any output ?

Comment: Sorry im about 3 months late, i hope the problem is solved, else it sounds like there is a conflicting port, try and run netstat or change the port in the config file.

Comment: I dont know if you solved it yet, but i was getting same problem when using windows 8.1 - Closing down skype actually helped with this. Might be worth tryingout.

Comment: Now i got a computer with windows 8.1 and skype uses reserved ports for comunication. Either change the ports to something unused or close skype while loading Apache, and fire up skype after and skype will re assign ports.